# How to display multiple Hyperlinks in Java

Tags: java, hyperlink, jeditorpane

I want to display multiple Hyperlinks using `JEditorPane`.To be more specific i have a `HashSet` named urlLinks:

```
static Set<String> urlList = new HashSet<>();
```

and inside it I store  urls like

www.google.com

www.facebook.com

etc.

As i said i am using the `JEditorPane` and I set it like this:

```
static final JEditorPane ResultsArea = new JEditorPane();
ResultsArea.setEditorKit(JEditorPane.createEditorKitForContentType("text/html"));
ResultsArea.setEditable(false);
```

At some point I want to display on the JEditorPane all these links as `Hyperlinks`
so I do this:

```
for(String s : urlList)
{

    s=("<a href=" +s+ ">"+s+"</a>"+"\n"); 

    ResultsArea.setText(ResultsArea.getText()+s+"\n");

}
```

but it doesn't display anything.
When i try to change it like this

```
ResultsArea.setText(s);
```

it displays me only one of them.However I want to display all of them one after the other
like

www.example.com

www.stackoverflow.com

etc.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `StringBuilder` to build the list of URLs first.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String s : urlList) {
    sb.append("<a href=").append(s).append(">").append(s).append("</a>\n");
}

ResultsArea.setText(sb.toString()); // then set the complete URL list once
```